# Iterating over a string separated by unescaped characters only

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell

Say I have the following string:

```
var="One two three\ four five"
```

What command would have the following code:

```
for item in "$(operation on $var)"; do
  echo "$item"
done
```

and produce the following output:

```
One
two
three four
five
```

Alternatively, could I use single quotes to achieve this on a string input that is already wrapped in double quotes? I.e., could I have the string

```
var="One two 'three four' five"
```

produce the same output under the above conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `gnu grep` in `perl` mode:

```
var="One two three\ four five"
grep -oP '[^\s\\]+(\\.[^\s\\]+)*' <<< "$var"
```

**Regex Details:**

- `[^\s\\]+`: Match 1+ of any non-whitespace character that is not `\`
- `(`: Start group

  - `\\.[^\s\\]+`: Match `\` followed by any escaped character followed by another string containing 1+ non-whitespace and non-backslash characters.
- `)*`: End group. Match 0 or more of this group.

```
One
two
three\ four
five
```

Here is **posix version** of same `grep`:

```
grep -oE '[^\\[:blank:]]+(\\.[^\\[:blank:]]+)*' <<< "$var"
```

If you want to loop through these strings in a loop:

```
while IFS= read -r str; do
   echo "$str"
done < <(grep -oP '[^\s\\]+(\\.\S+)*' <<< "$var")
```

Comment: Very nice answer, 2 mins til I can accept. If you knew how to make it POSIX compliant... :O I think I could wangle sed to do something posixly

Comment: I have added POSIX version of `grep` as well.

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you

Comment: What's the expected behaviour if there are two backslashes, or three backslashes, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend off of anubhava's thorough answer for the first case (`"\ "`), here's the answer for the second case (`"' '"`):

```
echo "one two 'three four three and a half' five" | 
  grep -oE "('([^'[:blank:]]+ )+[^'[:blank:]]+'|[^'[:blank:]]+)"
```

outputs:

```
one
two
'three four three and a half'
five
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an array:

```
arr=(one two 'three four' five)
for item in "${arr[@]}" ; do
    echo "$item"
done
```

Comment: The entire string will be within double quotes, so I don't believe this will work.

Comment: @NickBull: Where is the string coming from?

Comment: function argument, has to be quoted to not interfere with trailing arguments

Comment: @NickBull: So fix it, use separate arguments with a special argument meaning "this is the last one".

Comment: If it was that easy choroba ;) Unfortunately this is the way the source of the input is formatted. The function is used with input from a single string from an application that already exists and I can't control the format of the output from. Placing this at the end or the beginning has no effect on that. So while I agree that if I had control of the input that that is a great idea, but that isn't the case. Even if I write this as a function with the arguments formatted as you suggested, I'd still need to format the string this way prior to calling the function.

Comment: Also as another case, what if I had a further dynamically sized set of variables after these? Say `f one two three a b c`, where the first three are for this first input and the latter for other arguments. Perhaps using a delimiter between them would work, but it's going to be a pretty esoteric function to use. What if one of the dynamic arguments is the value of the delimiter? Or if one of the values contained that delimiter, etc. etc. etc.